# Why can't I call my function(C)?

Tags: c, function, struct, arguments, readfile

This is part of a program where I call a function that reads components from a ".dat" file and save the input to members of a Struct. When I try calling the function from my main.c it gives various errors depending on what I try. Most notably: conflicting types of 'ReadFile' and too few arguments to function 'ReadFile'. I also get a warning "passing argument from 'ReadFile' makes integer from pointer without cast" and some infos.

This is main.c

```
#include "MyData.h"
#include "NodalA.h"
#include "FileHandling.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "windows.h"

int main(){

    ComponentType *CircuitData;
    int numComp = 6;
    int numEl = 0;
    int numNodes = 0;
    CircuitData = malloc((numComp)*sizeof(ComponentType));
    ReadFile(CircuitData, &numEl, &numNodes);

    return 0;
}
```

This is FileHandling.c:

```
#include "FileHandling.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void ReadFile(ComponentType *CircuitData, int *numEl, int *numNodes){
    numEl = 0;
    numNodes = 0;

    int index = 0;

    FILE *data;
    data = fopen("mydata.dat", "r");

    if (data == NULL){
        printf("Error: \"mydata.dat\" could not be opened");
    }
    else {
        while(!feof(data)){
            fscanf(data, "%s, %s, %s, %f", CircuitData[index].name, CircuitData[index].node1, CircuitData[index].node2, CircuitData[index].value);

            *CircuitData[index].node1 = extractInteger(CircuitData[index].node1);
            *CircuitData[index].node2 = extractInteger(CircuitData[index].node2);

            if(*CircuitData[index].node1 > *numNodes)
                *numNodes = *CircuitData[index].node1;

            if(*CircuitData[index].node2 > *numNodes)
                *numNodes = *CircuitData[index].node2;

            numEl++;
            index++;
        }
    }

    fclose(data);
}
```

And this is MyData.h

```
#ifndef MYDATA_H_
#define MYDATA_H_


typedef struct Comp{
    char name[5];   //Name of circuit component
    char node1[5], node2[5];    //2 nodes
    float value[5]; //value
}ComponentType;

#endif /* MYDATA_H_ */
```

Any help would be appreciated. There are more code but I think this is the most important part.

Comment: what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Please note that most C compilers don't abort compilation in the first error, which means your error may be unrelated to the function declaration.

Comment: I have a feeling your `ReadFile` is clashing with another `ReadFile` that exists in the windows APIs.  Could you post the entire build log?

Comment: @GeorgeMitchell Im not sure what you mean with entire build log?

Comment: @hexa at the moment I'm getting "conflicting ReadFile and too few arguments

Comment: Okay I figured it out thanks to the hints on ReadFile maybe clashing with windows. I imported windows.h which I didnt need and when I removed it problems solved. I also forgot to import stdlib.h Thank you everyone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ReadFile function name used in the program is the same as a ReadFile function in "windows.h". The error "too few arguments to function 'ReadFile'" is most likely caused by the program trying to call the the function from windows with the wrong arguments. Removing "windows.h" or renaming the function ReadFile to something else solves the problem.